# What is the correct Xpath query to access an element in Perl's XML::LibXML?

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

I'm trying to access an element called raw data, inside some `<rawData>data is here</rawData>` tags.  However this XPath query with Perl's [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML) is not working:

```
foreach my $m ($xc->findnodes(q<//ns:wave[@waveID='1']/ns:well/oneDataSet/rawData>)) {
    print $m->textContent, "\n";
}
```

but a similar query to get an attribute `@wellName` is working fine:

```
foreach my $n ($xc->findnodes(q<//ns:wave[@waveID='1']/ns:well/@wellName>)) {
    print $n->textContent, "\n";
}
```

What is wrong with my syntax above for accessing the element?

Comment: This is something like the fifth XPath question you've asked over the past couple days. Have you thought of buying a couple XML and XPath books?

Comment: Sure, do you have any to recommend?

Comment: I've heard good things about "XPath & XPointer" by John Simpson (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002916). I haven't read it myself since (fortunately) my XML days are largely behind me. But O'Reilly publications are often a good bet.

Comment: I don't think buying a book on the topic is really necessary. XPath is actually *drop-dead easy* and everything about it can be learned from a plethora of web pages in less than one day. (There is no exaggeration or irony in this comment.)

Comment: In what way is it not working? Not finding any nodes? dieing?, nodes having no content? This, and showing a sample of the relevant XML will help to find what's wrong.

Comment: As always, a small and complete sample script with sample input is very helpful for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks all, I fixed it using getElementsByTagName('rawData');

Comment: @Tomalak: I must be *drop-dead stupid*, then.  Have you ever tried to do anything with documents with multiple namespaces? Are you silently assuming XPath 2?

Comment: @reinierpost No, I'm assuming XPath 1.0. I'm not sure what difficulties namespaces wold add to the subject (apart from requiring a general grasp on XML namespaces). Of course it's possible to write complex XPath that does advanced things like finding a maximum value or expressing an if/then/else. But generally speaking XPath is pretty straight-forward. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm not sure - if I knew how to deal with all those things I don't know how to do in XPath, I might be able to tell you.

Comment: @reinierpost I'm not saying *you* should not buy a book about XPath. I'm saying that XPath isn't all that complex and I would have a hard time finding something in such a book that isn't self-evident. Plus the Internet is full of real-world examples, for free. I'm not a book-learner. If you are, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your XML, I couldn't be sure but `//ns:wave[@waveID='1']/ns:well/oneDataSet/rawData` would make me wonder what namespace `oneDataSet` and `rawData` are supposed to be in. Do you need to prefix them?